# Is it possible to listen to AWS SNS notifications without using public callbacks?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm just getting started with SNS and as far as I see you cannot simply subscribe to the publisher and listen to events. You have to i). create a publically accessible callback (url/email/sms), ii). register it with the service and iii). build a consumer specific to the type of callback.

I want to use an API similar to this:

```
const client = new SnsClient({
  region: 'eu-west-1',
  topicArn: 'XXX'
})
client.on('connection', (connection) => {
  connection.on('notification', (notification) => {
    // do some work with notification
  })
})
```

Am I missing something? I want to have X number of web servers listening to a single event (fanout).

For instance my worker might be an EC2 instance on a private subnet, so the available subscriptions: "http(s)", "email", "sms" wouldn't work**. "SQS" could work but you have to set a queue up for each instance and it uses long polling rather than push. "application" and "lambda" are not applicable.

Is AWS SNS suitable for this use case? If not is there an alternative AWS service?

** You might be able to get https to work but only with overly complex roles/dns.

**Edit:**
I think what I want to do is similar to [Google Cloud PubSub Subscription](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/pubsub/0.13.1/pubsub/subscription) or [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-javascript.html) but using a native (AWS) rather than 3rd party service.

Comment: Are you asking about [fanout scenario](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNS_Scenarios.html#SNSFanoutScenario)?

Comment: @AlexBlex kind of but I more interested in the **connection**. I don't want to have to create callbacks and subscribers for my instances. I want to simply have a "socket like" connection. My instinct is that I need a different product but cannot identify a suitable AWS one. Wiring up a separate queue for each instances seems unnecessary.

Comment: Well, you probably need to elaborate what is the "socket like" connection then. Both pubsub and rabbit require all consumers to subscribe. The subscriptions are quite "socket like" tho.

Comment: @AlexBlex as far as I can see in order to use SNS you need to register subscriber callbacks. This requires you to i). publish a public URL (for each node) and ii). register it with SNS. If you have a dynamic number of nodes this is quite a bit of work to setup/take down. I'd rather just spin up a node, make a connection to the publisher and then listen to events. PubSub does require a named subscription but it's simpler than SNS and RabbitMQ allows you to just connect to and consume messages sent on an exchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "SQS" could work but you have to set a queue up for each instance and it uses long polling rather than push.

SQS is exactly the way to implement what you have described, in AWS.  SNS does not support a `connection.on('notification',...` style of operation, but this is exactly how SQS long polling works, in practice.

Don't be confused by the phrase "long polling."  Yes, technically that's what it is, but it's very much a legitimate push operation that occurs over the long poll -- if you're, say, 5 seconds into a 20 second long poll against an empty queue, the next message that arrives will *immediately* cause your long poll to return that one message.  Now. Not in another 15 seconds.  You don't sit around and wait for more, even if you asked for more.  Long polling is essentially a push-wrapper in SQS.

Note that you don't necessarily have to define the fan-out queues up front.  Each listener can create a queue for itself, subscribe the queue to the topic, and start listening.

Or... there's the message broker in AWS IoT.  Some might say this is a little unorthodox of an application, but it appears to support multiple subscribers to one topic.

> The message broker maintains a list of all client sessions and the subscriptions for each session. When a message is published on a topic, the broker checks for sessions with subscriptions that map to the topic. The broker then forwards the publish message to all sessions that have a currently connected client.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-message-broker.html

It supports MQTT over TCP, and MQTT over web sockets, with TLS in both cases.

Comment: IoT Message Broker looks interesting but has it's own problems... registering "devices" and distributing client certs does not simplify things. Accepting answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

edit: found this npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqs-consumer
allows you to write like so:

```
consumer.on('message_received', function(message){
  console.log(message)
})
```

Came here looking for the same as OP. SNS has subscriber options but like you said, you have to manually create the subscriber and handle all of that nonsense. don't use long polling. I'm going to explore something like RXDB or some type of message queue like ZeroMQ or RabbitMQ. Or if it's simple enough of an implementation, just another node server with websockets.